# Execute CSS inside jQuery only if body class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

i'm trying to execute css (display: none;) inside script to hide elements from my menu only if one language is active so the body class changes from one language to another and i want the script to check if the body class of X language active to execute css display none else display block.
i already tried it in  at the bottom of the footer and i don't know what let it happens, just do not work...

```
$('body').hasClass('translatepress-ru_RU') {
  $("#menu-item-17728").css("display","none");
}
```

Comment: Oh my! Thats actually worked and i struggled and thought i need to bring here JS at all... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with css.

```
body.translatepress-ru_RU #menu-item-17728{
    display:none;
 }
```